# 2d array declaration with malloc - explanation to the answer (parameters)

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

I know that there have been posted some questions about 2d arrays with malloc, however, I would like to refer to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17236526/13493580) to one of those questions.

I cannot visualise the realisation of the following fragment:

*Allocate an array of M rows of N columns like this:*

```
int (*array)[N] = malloc(M * sizeof *array);
```

1. If we have M rows, why does `*array` have N parameter?
2. What is the size of the `*array` (also as a number)? I understand the result of the part with malloc() only as M*N, but single block (1d) of the structure.
3. How does M size, passed only in malloc, becomes number of rows? How does it become `*array[M][N]`?

I would appreciate your answers.

Comment: 1. `N` is the number of columns. 2. `*array` is an array of `N` `int`s, so `sizeof *array` equals `N * sizeof(int)`, and `M * sizeof *array` equals `M * N * sizeof(int)`. 3. `malloc(M * sizeof *array)` is equivalent to `malloc(M * N * sizeof(int))`. Unlike declared objects, blocks allocated by `malloc` do not have an effective type, only an allocated size.

Comment: The allocated block has the correct size and alignment so that it can hold the contents of an `int[M][N]`. The return value of `malloc` is converted to the type of `array`, which is `int(*)[N]` (a pointer to an array of `N` `int`s). In the expression `array[i][j]`, the `array[i]` selects a row of type `int[N]` which is an array of `N` `int`s. The array is converted by the expression to an `int *` pointing to the first element of the row. The `[j]` operates on that `int *` to select a particular element of the row. So effectively `array[i][j]` selects an element at a row and column.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, it starts to be clearer for me. However, could you tell me, why does these questions are so bad that the post is downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

> If we have M rows, why does *array have N parameter?
> How does M size, passed only in malloc, becomes number of rows?

The code in the question is a simplified version of the most correct way to write the expression:

```
int (*array)[M][N] = malloc(sizeof *array);
```

This form is however problematic to use, because now we must access the array as `(*array)[i][j]` which is strange and cumbersome.

Therefore there's a trick to leave out the left-most dimension and use a pointer to the first element instead. The first element of an `int [M][N]` is a `int [N]` and a pointer to such an element is `int(*)[N]`.

With `int (*array)[N]` we can access the array as `array[i][j]`, where the `[i]` is pointer arithmetic on a `int(*)[N]` type and the `[j]` is pointer arithmetic on a `int*` (a decayed `int [N]` array).

> What is the size of the *array

It is `sizeof(int [N])` bytes, or if you will `sizeof(int)*N` bytes.

More details can be found here: [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)